# The last row of DataTable is always an ADD NEW ROW

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I'm using `JSF 2.2` and `PrimeFaces 6.1`. I want to create a `DataTable` in which the last row is always an **add new row**.

For example, suppose I have 2 Entities `Purchase` and `Article`, these two Entities are related with a many to many relationship. In the view of Purchase, I will have a list of articles (data table), at start the table is empty, I want the empty table to contain one row to add a new article, this "add row" should always be there to add new articles.

The table of articles have 3 columns: name, amount and price.

The entity of Purchase is:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="purchase")
    public class Purchase implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        private int numberArticle;
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date datePurchase;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "join_purchase_article",
                   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "purchase_id"),
                   inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id"))
        private List<Article> listArticles =  new ArrayList();
    }
```

The entity of Article:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
public class Article implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private int amount;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "listArticles")
    private List<Purchase> listPurchase =  new ArrayList();
}
```

My XHTML page looks like:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel>
        <p:dataTable id="idTable" value="#{addPurchaseController.listArticlePurchase}" var="article">
            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{article.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Amount">
                 <h:outputText value="#{article.amount}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Price">
                <h:outputText value="#{article.price}"/>
            </p:column>            
        </p:dataTable>
    </a:panel>
</h:form>
```

The Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "addPurchaseController")
@ViewScoped
public class AddPurchaseController implements Serializable {

    private List<Article> listArticlePurchase;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        initialisation();
    }

    private void initialisation() {
        listArticlePurchase= new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You effectively describe in your question how you should approach it. Always add an empty entity in the list, Check if you are at the last entry in the list and render inputs then instead of outputs...

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you for the reply, can you please tell me how to "check if you are at the last entry in the list" in `Facelets` I intend to use `rendered="#{}"` but I don't know what to write inside the rendered. please help me.

Comment: To know if you are at the last one, you need to know the index and the size... You have a list of which you can determine the size. In addition you have a current item or you can use the varStatus attribute. Combine these and you have a solution. Please think on how you'd solve this in plain java and then extrapolate (or try to) EL/XHTML/JSF...

Comment: By new article you mean that this Article doesn't exist in the DB or should be choosen from a list ?

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi I mean it does not exist in the database.